# Apresentar uma div por tempo determinado Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Gostaria de saber, se tem como eu apresentar o conteudo de uma div em um tempo determinado. Pois nesse caso estou inserindo um html na div e depois de um tempo gostaria que ela sumisse, tem alguma forma de fazer isso?

```
    <div id="alerta">

    </div>

@if (cadastradoComSucesso)
{
    <script>
        var functionSuccess = function () {
            $('#alerta').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Registro cadastrado com sucesso.</div>')
        };        
        setTimeout(functionSuccess, 8000);     
    </script>
}
else
{
    <script>
        var functionWarrning = function () {
            $('#alerta').html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"> Erro ao salvar registro.</div>')
        };
        setTimeout(functionWarrning, 8000);        
    </script>

}
```

Comment: O que tem dentro da sua função? Tentou o `$().hide` do jQuery?

Comment: Então, mas no caso, como eu chamaria o hide? teria que ter um timer para isso não?

Comment: O seu setTimeOut já não faz isso?

Comment: Eu sinceramente não sei como a pergunta foi positivada, ela não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa, já que é algo que se deve ter umas 8000 duplicatas aqui no Stack... uma rápida `googlada` já da a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o setTimeout e depois dar o hide na div.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   //Esconde a div
   $('#alerta').hide();
}, seu_tempo_em_millisegundos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui dessa forma:

```
<script>
    var functionWarrning = function () {
        $('#alerta').html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"> Erro ao salvar registro.</div>')
        $('#alerta').show();
    };

    functionWarrning();

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#alerta').hide();
    }, 8000);         
</script>
```

Comment: Mas aí a div ainda vai continuar com o conteúdo, mesmo escondida.

Comment: Neste caso pra mim não tem problema, pois como estou colocando o conteudo com .html e não append, ele subistitu tudo que tem dentro da div.

Comment: Estranho. Vc faz a pergunta, um monte de gente responde e depois quase no mesmo momento vc responde a sua própria pergunta com a mesma solução das outras respostas.

Comment: @Dvd Só complementei como eu consegui resolver o problema, e claro, juntando todas as ajudas dadas por nossos amigos. As vezes isso pode ajudar alguém no futuro, sabendo como resolvi de fato o problema

Comment: Então não é uma resposta, seria apenas uma edição da pergunta, já que marcou outra resposta como "correta".